# Javascript Autocomplete change from Id to Name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a problem with one of my forms. I am using autocomplete function for input with unique Name, but the class will be different every time. I Would like to use autocomplete with getElementsbyName and not with ID, since ID will be different every time. Is it possible to change my script so it would use Name of input instead of ID.

Here is my input:

```js
function autocomplete(searchEle, arr) {
    var currentFocus;
    searchEle.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
        var divCreate,
            b,
            i,
            fieldVal = this.value;
        closeAllLists();
        if (!fieldVal) {
            return false;
        }
        currentFocus = -1;
        divCreate = document.createElement("DIV");
        divCreate.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        divCreate.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
        this.parentNode.appendChild(divCreate);
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].substr(0, fieldVal.length).toUpperCase() == fieldVal.toUpperCase()) {
                b = document.createElement("DIV");
                b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, fieldVal.length) + "</strong>";
                b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(fieldVal.length);
                b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    searchEle.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                    closeAllLists();
                });
                divCreate.appendChild(b);
            }
        }
    });
    searchEle.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        var autocompleteList = document.getElementById(
            this.id + "autocomplete-list"
        );
        if (autocompleteList)
            autocompleteList = autocompleteList.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            currentFocus++;
            addActive(autocompleteList);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            //up
            currentFocus--;
            addActive(autocompleteList);
        } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
                if (autocompleteList) autocompleteList[currentFocus].click();
            }
        }
    });

    function addActive(autocompleteList) {
        if (!autocompleteList) return false;
        removeActive(autocompleteList);
        if (currentFocus >= autocompleteList.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = autocompleteList.length - 1;
        autocompleteList[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    }

    function removeActive(autocompleteList) {
        for (var i = 0; i < autocompleteList.length; i++) {
            autocompleteList[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
        }
    }

    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        var autocompleteList = document.getElementsByClassName(
            "autocomplete-items"
        );
        for (var i = 0; i < autocompleteList.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt != autocompleteList[i] && elmnt != searchEle) {
                autocompleteList[i].parentNode.removeChild(autocompleteList[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
}
var animals = [

    "Salaj",
    "Bihor",
    "Arad",
    
];
autocomplete(document.getElementById("animal"), animals);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 body {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
 }
 .autocomplete {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 input {
    border: none;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
 }
 input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
 }
 input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
 .autocomplete-items {
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
 }
 .autocomplete-items div {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #8e26d4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
 }
 .autocomplete-items div:hover {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
 }
 .autocomplete-active {
    background-color: rgb(30, 255, 169) !important;
    color: #ffffff;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Autocomplete Example</h1>
<form autocomplete="off">
<div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
<input id="animal" type="text" name="animal" placeholder="Animals" />
</div>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you all in advance for the help.

Comment: You can use `var mySpecialInput = document.querySelector("input[name='uniquename']")` to select by CSS selector

Comment: Tried with classname ?